# why PROVIDER_CHANGED not working in android studio?

Tags: android, gmail, provider, incoming-mail

**i want to show simple toast on new email came in android studio....i am using Receiver but that is not being fired...**

```
 <receiver
            android:name=".MyReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROVIDER_CHANGED"/>
                <data android:scheme="content"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

**And in Receiver**

```
 @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Mail received ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.i("mail","mail received");
    context.startActivity(new Intent(context,BottemNavigationActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I  hope this is what you were looking for. You can also register in the `service` rather than doing it in `manifest`

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String action = intent.getAction();

        if(action.equals("com.example.app.START"))    {  
            Toast.makeText(context, "your message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } 
    }

}
```

Comment: sorry my question is that how to launch my own app on new email received ?

Answer (score 0):

Since receiving an email is not a part of the OS, you need to register the trigger for a specific app, like `Gmail`. To do that, you need to write these in your manifest:

```
<receiver android:name="GmailReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROVIDER_CHANGED"
                android:priority="-10">
            </action>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="content" android:host="gmail-ls"
                android:pathPattern="/unread/.*">
            </data>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

And then to receive those emails:

```
public class GmailReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    Context context;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Email Received!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry i tried it earlier i found same here it didnot worked

Comment: i did the same but receiver is not being fired....is there something extra to do? when i do with another intent i.e on AirPlane_MODE the same receiver is being called.